How can one Refute Richard Carrier's claim of "Jesus Mythicism" in Gal. 4:4?
"The Christ myth theory, also known as the Jesus myth theory, Jesus mythicism, or the Jesus ahistoricity theory, is the view that the story of Jesus is a work of mythology with no historical substance".
Could someone here respond to Richard Carrier's claim of Galatians 4:4 "born" of a woman. He claims it means "made". I think it means "borne" by a woman. Richard also finds a problem in Galatians 1:19 where it says "brother"; but he claims it means "brothers" of the Lord. Could any of you reply to him?

Gal 4:4 - But when the fullness of the time had come, God sent forth
His Son, having been born of a woman, having been born under the Law,


Gal 1:19 - But I saw none of the other apostles, only James, the
Lord's brother.


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Please also provide a link to the material to which you refer.

I don't understand your question.  "Born of a woman" is in 4:4 not 1:9 and the reference to sons is by adoption, not physical birth.

The question should include a direct quotation of "Richard's carrier's claim" and whichever verses of scripture he refers to. Don't make every individual reader have to do the research that could be provided within the question.

Is this blog he meant? https://www.richardcarrier.info/archives/15057

And this blog regarding "James the Lord's brother". https://www.richardcarrier.info/archives/11516. According to Mark 6:3 the Bible would have been clearer if it read: "James, one of the Lord's  brothers".

@Constantthin  Not to suggest any viewpoint about Galatians  1:19 that you might hold, but, my question to Carrier is, "why complicate it?"  He suggests that Paul makes things more complicated by the way Paul's worded it.  And now he's suggesting that Paul should make it more complex.  "James, the Lord's brother" is simple.  It doesn't arbitrarily bring in other brothers Jesus had.  It's stated quite simply and clearly.  See my answer below for a much fully treatment.

@Mike Sangrey. I found Richard Carrier to be very confusing. Don’t understand much of his reasoning. I think you hit the nail on its head in your last sentence about him supplying more quantity than quality. I greatly suspect Richard Carrier to be, if not one himself, using an  AI ChatBot. // The James thingy was just my personal brief observation.

But, I see now how it was phrased only to distinguish this James from the other James, who was not Jesus’ brother.

You should ask the question “How can one refute the Apostle Paul’s claim of Jesus mythicism?”
1 Timothy 1:4 or to devote themselves to myths and endless genealogies. Such things promote controversial speculations rather than advancing God’s work—which is by faith.

For Galatians 4:4, γίνομαι (become, come into being, born; consensus has moved to the lexeme γίγνομαι) is very well attested to mean 'born' when used for persons.  A wonderful resource, providing lexicons in a couple of different languages, is Logeion.  Here is the link to γίγνομαι.  The first entry says:

abs., come into being opp. εἶναι, Emp. 17.11, Pl. Phd. 102e, cf. Ti.
29a; and so,
of persons, to be born, νέον γεγαώς new born, Od. 19.400; ὑπὸ Τμώλῳ
γεγαῶτας born (and so living) under Tmolus, Il. 2.866; ἢ πρόσθε θανεῖν
ἢ ἔπειτα γ. Hes. Op. 175; γιγνομέναισι λάχη τάδʼ . . ἐκράνθη at our
birth, A. Eu. 347; γ. ἔκ τινος Il. 5.548, Hdt. 7.11; πατρὸς ἐκ ταὐτοῦ
E. IA 406, cf. Isoc. 5.136; σέθεν . . ἐξ αἵματος A. Th. 142; less
freq. ἀπό τινος Hdt. 8.22, etc.; ἐσθλῶν E. Hec. 380, etc.; γεγονέναι
κακῶς, καλῶς, Ar. Eq. 218, Isoc. 7.37, etc.; κάλλιον, εὖ, Hdt. 1.146,
3.69; τὸ μὴ γενέσθαι not to have been born, A. Fr. 401: freq. with Numerals, ἔτεα τρία καὶ δέκα γεγονώς Hdt. 1.119; ἀμφὶ τὰ πέντε ἢ
ἑκκαίδεκα ἔτη γενόμενος X. Cyr. 1.4.16; γεγονὼς ἔτη περὶ πεντήκοντα D.
21.154; οἱ ὑπὲρ τὰ στρατεύσιμα ἔτη γεγονότες those of an age beyond . ., X. Cyr. 1.2.4: c. gen., γεγονὼς πλειόνων ἐτῶν ἢ πεντήκοντα Pl. Lg.
951c, etc.: rarely with ordinals, ὀγδοηκοστὸν ἔτος γεγονώς Luc. Macr.
22, cf. Plu. Phil. 18.

There's no doubt that γίγνομαι means 'born' in the Galatians 4:4 text.
For Galatians 1:19, εἰ μὴ Ἰάκωβον τὸν ἀδελφὸν τοῦ κυρίου (Literally: "except James, the brother of the Lord"), the word ἀδελφὸν is the singular accusative of ἀδελφός ("brother").  You can't make it say 'brothers'; it's not plural.  Note that Richard Carrier isn't actually saying it's plural.  He's saying that James is a member of the brotherhood.
So, let's deal with that.  Having read Carrier's argument (setting aside his flippant attitude and the tedious repetition of 'peer review', a term which, to be consistent, he should very precisely define), I understand he's arguing that Paul's statement in Gal. 1:19 means something like, "James, someone distinct from being an Apostle of the Lord and who should just be thought of as a brother."
In order to support this argument he has to take εἰ μὴ (very well attested to function as a conjunction meaning, "except") to refer to 'brother' as the exception to the 'Apostles' and not, James, as an exception to a defined set of people he did not meet with.  He argues that εἰ μὴ signals to the reader that a comparative is to be expected.  It's true that a comparison is being made (like the comparative 'taller' suggests others are not as tall).  But, he claims that the comparison is between those who are Apostles and those who aren't.  But the focus-topic is on who Paul met with.  He stayed with Cephas and didn't see any other Apostles except for James.  The comparison is between two sets of people, those he saw and those he didn't.  Cephas is also presented as an exception to those he didn't meet with, but in this case, it's length of time.
So, Paul supports his defense by making three points:

I met with Peter for 15 days.
I met with James who is the Lord's brother.
I didn't meet with anyone else.

The implication is that anyone who questions Paul should consult with these two very clearly defined people.
Carrier's logic is not only convoluted, but, to use an expression Carrier uses, not what the Greek says.
Also, the form,
  name-of-person    phrase-disambiguating-from-the-set-of-names

is a very well attested grammatical structure.  For example, Matthew 10:3

Philip and Bartholomew; Thomas and Matthew the tax collector; James
the son of Alphaeus, and Thaddaeus;

That verse refers to one of the Matthews (a common name), namely, the tax collector one, and to a specific James (a common name), the son of Alphaeus (which is a different James than the well known James referred to in Galatians).
To say what Carrier wants Paul to say, Paul would have written:

εἰ μὴ Ἰάκωβον τὸν ἀδελφὸν ἐν τοῦ κυρίου

Literally, "Except James, the brother in the Lord", note the ἐν.  See Ephesians 6:21 for a similar example.  The ἐν is actually quite critical to use when referring to a brotherhood.  Otherwise, the plain sense is biological relationship.  The word ἐν places the person in a larger sphere.
Paul could have also simply said,

εἰ μὴ Ἰάκωβον τὸν ἀδελφὸν ἡμῶν

Literally, "except James, our brother."
The straight-forward, plain sense of Galatians 1:19 is that Paul only met with James and the expression, "brother of the Lord" is simply answering the very natural question, "which James is being referred to?"  For discussion of the various James that were relatively prominent in the early Church, you can consult any significant commentary on the epistle of James.  James, A commentary on the Greek Text, by William Varner, pages 3-10 is one good example.
The point being:  "Which James?" is a very natural question that Paul would have had to answer.  He is, after all, writing about a very specific meeting.  And, he's strongly supporting his argument, he's defending his ministry!  That is, "James, specifically the Lord's brother, will be a witness to what I'm saying.  Ask him."
Also, Carrier tries to make the point that Paul complicates things by writing what he wrote, unless one holds to Carrier's view.  The same argument can be made against Carrier's argument.  That is, if Paul meant what Carrier suggests, then why didn't Paul write something simpler, as suggested above?  Carrier's argument cuts both ways.
In addition, Carrier's interpretation of "brothers of the Lord" in 1 Corinthians 9:5 is easily dismissed. According to his view, it refers to all believers.  If that's true, then the plain reading of this text has Paul saying that all believers have wives.
Lastly, I find Richard Carrier to be disingenuous, which speaks to the convoluted logic he employs.  For example, he says,

The latter [referring to a quote from the NLT] is definitely not what the Greek says. It’s an
interpretation of what the translator thinks the Greek text means; but
it’s not what the text says. The former [refers to NIV] is closer to what the text
actually says. [emphasis mine]

But, two sentences later, quoting himself, he says,

And what he [ie Paul] means to say is that no one in Judea ever met him.

So, "Thank you, Dr. Carrier, for translating that for us."  The process of understanding a text, that is, obtaining meaning, is, by definition, interpretation.  Carrier demonstrates that himself by what he says, though he contradicts that by what he says.
To fully answer Dr. Carrier would take a much larger answer.  Not that his statements are not easily answered.  But, he's made up for that lack of quality by quantity.  I hope this answer will suffice.

Go more into detail

The literal Greek of Paul's letter to the Galatians reads as follows:

When however had come the fullness of the time sent forth God the Son
of him having been born of a woman/wife (gynaikos, SG1135) having
been born under [the] Law . . .

This distinction confirms the legitimacy of the birth of Yeshua to Miriam as the wife of Yosef.
The Greek Septuagint translation was created by Jewish scholars under the auspices of the Sanhedrin, the highest legislative and judicial assembly of ancient Israel. The Septuagint  dates back to the third century before Christ, representing a snapshot in time to how the text was interpreted then. In this translation, Isaiah 7:14 reads literally as follows (using English word order):

On account of this, [the] Lord (kurios) himself will give you a
sign--behold the virgin (parthenos, SG3933) will conceive in [the]
womb, and she shall bear a son, and you shall call his name Emmanuel
(Hebrew for "With us is God," SH6005).

Parthenos means a virgin, a woman who has never had sexual relations, which is precisely the word these pre-Christian Jewish scholars chose from the original Hebrew.
According to Benjamin Kantor, PhD, a Research Associate in Biblical Hebrew Philology at the University of Cambridge, the name Joshua in Hebrew is Yehoshu’a (yeho ‘SHOO wuh), which can be shortened to Yeshua (yeh ‘SHOO wuh). The name means "YHWH is salvation," and according to Isaiah's prophecy, the name, Yeshua, will be called or understood as "With us is God."
And this is precisely what happened.

Isaiah 7:14 was a prophecy for King Ahaz.

Really? The totally evil King Ahaz was the fulfillment of a sign from God in that everyone knows that King Ahaz was born of a virgin and was known as "With us is God"? Also note that Ahaz worshipped idols and even sacrificed his own children. Or perhaps, Isaiah saw beyond this worthless man to the King of Kings, giving hope to the faithful and righteous Israelites suffering under the rule of Ahaz.

Also of interest is that God created Adam in his own image out of dirt and then God took Havah out of Adam. After the fall, God promised Havah that her seed (i.e. not the seed of Adam) would crush serpent's head, and so it happened that Messiah was taken out of Miriam, the offspring of Havah by direct intervention of God by means of the Holy Spirit.

No, Isaiah 7:14 was fulfilled by the son of Ahaz, who was called King Hezekiah.

Ahaz was the evil king. Hezekiah was the good king.

Oh dear. So, it wasn't about Ahaz as you previously claimed. It's not about the meaning of the word, parthenos as was pointed out from the Septuagint translation, nor is it about a woman/wife under the Law as Paul explained. Apparently, this is all about a limitless supply of unsupported allegations and arguments from a succession of easily falsified claims. Sorry, I won't waste any more of my time. Count me out.
